# Two completely separated bibliographies in one document

Tags: biblatex, multiple-citations

I need two completely separated lists of bibliography in one document.

The first is just a regular reference list according to citations in the text. The second is supposed to contain only a subset of these entries, and it should start with [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQPIh.png) and go sequentially to [2], [3], ...

It is not related to the first references, but should be completely independent.

So far, I used

```
\usepackage[defernumbers=true,backref=true,backend=biber,style=ieee]{biblatex}
```

and then, after some citations, I put:

```
\printbibliography[title={References1},resetnumbers=true]
```

and after some more citations, I put:

```
\printbibliography[keyword=own,title={References2},resetnumbers=true]
```

Using the "keyword" filter, I was able to get a subset of the former citations, but the references do not start with [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQPIh.png) and aren't sorted correctly. In another trial, I used multibib, but there resetting the numbers led to wrong references being used in the text.

These two lists should just be completely independent - is that possible?

Here is a MWE with the biblatex approach:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[
defernumbers=true,
backref=true,
backend=biber,
style=ieee
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{diss.bib}
@techreport{Peherstorfer:2016,
title = {Survey of multifidelity methods in uncertainty propagation, inference, and optimization},
author = {Peherstorfer, B. and Willcox, K. and Gunzburger, M.},
volume = {Technical Report 16-1},
year = {2016},
institution = {Aerospace Computational Design Laboratory, Massachusetts Institute of Technology},
}

@Book{Baier:2008,
    month = {April},
    publisher = {MIT Press},
    title = {Principles of Model Checking},
    year = {2008},
    author = {Christel Baier and Joost-Pieter Katoen}
    }

@Book{Koenig:2013a,
    month = {November},
    publisher = {Oldenbourg Wissenschaftsverlag},
    title = {100 {\"U}bungsaufgaben zu Grundlagen der Informatik, Band II: Technische Informatik},
    year = {2013},
    type = {Book},
    author = {Lukas K{\"o}nig and Friederike Pfeiffer and Hartmut Schmeck},
    keywords = {own}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{diss.bib}

\begin{document}
some text... \cite{Peherstorfer:2016,Baier:2008,Koenig:2013a}

\printbibliography[title={References1},resetnumbers=true]

some more text...

\printbibliography[keyword=own,title={References2},resetnumbers=true]
\end{document}
```

This yields the following output:

[image]

But I need the numbering of References2 to start with 1 again (and, more importantly, to be sorted alphabetically; otherwise I could just use a sorting where all "own" references are put at the very beginning).

Comment: can you make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: I'm on it... not so easy...

Comment: Ok, I just added an MWE (don't know what the "B" means, hope it's accurate).

Comment: Thanks! The B stands for "B"ibliography, which you already have in your example, so everything is perfect.

Comment: In your example it is easy. `\newrefsection \newrefcontext[sorting=nyt] \nocite{*}` before the second bibliography should work.

Comment: Yeah, that's it!! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `refsection` could help. In the following example your own references will be sorted as they appear in the bib file, if you want another order, see [Ulrike Fischer's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376829/two-completely-separated-bibliographies-in-one-document/376834#comment933304_376829).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[
defernumbers=true,
backref=true,
backend=biber,
style=ieee
]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{diss.bib}
@techreport{Peherstorfer:2016,
title = {Survey of multifidelity methods in uncertainty propagation, inference, and optimization},
author = {Peherstorfer, B. and Willcox, K. and Gunzburger, M.},
volume = {Technical Report 16-1},
year = {2016},
institution = {Aerospace Computational Design Laboratory, Massachusetts Institute of Technology},
}

@Book{Baier:2008,
    month = {April},
    publisher = {MIT Press},
    title = {Principles of Model Checking},
    year = {2008},
    author = {Christel Baier and Joost-Pieter Katoen}
    }

@Book{Koenig:2013a,
    month = {November},
    publisher = {Oldenbourg Wissenschaftsverlag},
    title = {100 {\"U}bungsaufgaben zu Grundlagen der Informatik, Band II: Technische Informatik},
    year = {2013},
    type = {Book},
    author = {Lukas K{\"o}nig and Friederike Pfeiffer and Hartmut Schmeck},
    keywords = {own}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{diss.bib}

\begin{document}
some text... \cite{Peherstorfer:2016,Baier:2008,Koenig:2013a}

\printbibliography[title={References1}]

some more text...

\begin{refsection}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword=own,title={References2}]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]